# Admob test not working

Tags: java, android, admob

I cannot seem to get the admob test to work on a test app.   Can anyone point to a recent tutorial.  This is just a test so I just use Site URL: http://.  Will that work, or how do you test an app not on the market.  My code is similar to the Google sample:

```
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.LinearLayout;  

import com.google.ads.*;

public class testadmob extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxx"); 
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest(); // for testing
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad  
        request.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="1dip">
        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

I never see any errors on any logs.   It just sits there for hours. Any help is appreciated.
  A recent tutorial would help.  I have tried all xml with loadoncreate.   Same thing, just sits   there.

Thank you,
Lewis

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
<com.google.ads.AdView 
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="normal"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx"       
/>
```

Java:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxx”)
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView); 
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Tips:

addTestDevice was the phone id number taken from the console, not logcat, in eclipse.

Patience, it could be longer than the 2 minutes, much longer, like 30 minutes to get the first ad.

Put the ad at the top, it works best if you are starting out.   Once it is working, resist the desire to make very many changes at once.  It is harder to find the problem.

No paddingLeft  or paddingRight of even one dip or pixel.  It needs it all and would not work.

The slightest change can affect admob.  It is fragile and I scratched my head a few times.  After I slowed down and was more incremental, it fell into place. The key for me was  incremental. Work on other things if necessary and give it time.  I would also write down different configurations you have tried.  It helped me reason logically and not repeat dead ends.  The main thing – slow down.

Lewis

Comment: FYI, new to AdMob 4.3.1 you can add test devices in xml: `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx,etc"`

Comment: my console gives: utomatic Target Mode: using device '0123456789ABCDEF'  I've tried all sorts of device id numbers obtained from code requests, logcat, google examples, etc and ultimately had to give up on admob because could never grid rid of the invalid ad request error in trying to get the first test ad.